# Is there a book / paper / theory where the Cartan-Eilenberg homology of Lie algebras consider representations on Lie algebras again?

Tags: reference-request, linear-transformations, lie-algebras, homology-cohomology

I know the standard theorems and concepts of Cartan-Eilenberg complexes for Lie algebras. They use operations $\mathfrak{g}\longrightarrow \mathfrak{gl}(V)$, if not even the adjoint representation $\mathfrak{g}\longrightarrow \mathfrak{gl(g)}.$ And on top, they seem to prefer semisimple $\mathfrak{g}.$

I am especially interested in solvable $\mathfrak{g}$ and representations $\mathfrak{g}\longrightarrow \mathfrak{gl(I(g))}$ where $\mathfrak{I(g)}$ are again Lie algebras, invariants of the original Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}.$

My examples are
\begin{align*}
\mathfrak{I(g)}=\mathfrak{A(g)}&= \left\{ \alpha \in \mathfrak{gl(g)} \,|\,[\alpha(X),Y]+[X,\alpha(Y)]=0 \right\} \\
\mathfrak{I(g)}=\Phi(\mathfrak{g)}&=\left\{\varphi \in \mathfrak{A(g)}\,|\,[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}]\subseteq \operatorname{ker}(\varphi)\right\}
\end{align*}
They are $\mathfrak{g}$-modules and Lie algebras in their own right: $X.\alpha =[\operatorname{ad}(X),\alpha ]$. What makes them interesting is that the more complicated the multiplication in $\mathfrak{g}$ is, the easier the multiplication in those invariant Lie algebras is, and vice versa. E.g. $\mathfrak{A(g)}\cong \mathbb{C}$ if $\mathfrak{g}$ is the Borel subalgebra of a simple Lie algebra. And, of course, $\mathfrak{A}(\left\{a\right\})=\mathfrak{gl(a)}$ for abelian $\mathfrak{a}.$ However, all the interesting stuff happens in between.

Since those invariants are $\mathfrak{g}$-modules, I wonder if there is a homological theory in cases where the representation space isn't only a vector space but a Lie algebra again. E.g. $\mathfrak{A(g)}$ allows a tower and semidirect products via their module property.

And ...

... have those invariants been considered before?